# starting new row in plot grid using par mfrow in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a very simple question.

I use `par(mfrow=c(x,y))` regularly to create grids of plots.  Let's say I execute  `par(mfrow=c(6,6))` to create a grid.  I then make 10 plots simply by plotting stuff in sequence.  How can I make it such that the next plot starts in the next row (instead of continuing in the next column)?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried mfcol ?

Comment: mfcol would simply get the plots to traverse the grid in column-order, right?  I need to "break" to the next row...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `layout`? It allows to specify the order of the plots.

```
layout(matrix(c(4,1,3,2),nrow=2))
for (i in 1:4) {
  plot(seq_len(i))
}
```